# OS X fighting with curl SSL - certificate error

Tags: curl, ssl, openssl, certificate, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to use curl w SSL, and I am getting a permanent error regarding the certificate.
I know that OSX is a mess regarding curl certificate , and I guess I forgot an important process after creating my own self-signed certificate for dev  (node_ssl_server.local on my localhost)

the error :

```
curl --verbose --header "Authorization: Bearer b8232aedb20e0a97499b3bffa9d3edeb3c1b25" https://node_ssl_server.local:8000/Categories
* About to connect() to node_ssl_server.local port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.13...
* connected
* Connected to node_ssl_server.local (192.168.1.13) port 8000 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/share/curl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. 
Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    * Closing connection #0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

what I did previously to create my self-signed certificate:

```
    cd /etc/ssl/self-signed
    sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048
    sudo openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key
    sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out server.pass.key 2048
    sudo openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in server.pass.key -out server.key
    sudo rm server.pass.key
    sudo openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
    ..
    >Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:node_ssl_server.local
    ..
    sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

so I got my self-signed certificate into /etc/ssl/self-signed:

```
    ls /etc/ssl/self-signed
    > server.crt    server.csr  server.key
```

and my curl cacert.pem into /usr/share/curl :

```
    ls /usr/share/curl 
    > cacert.pem
```

I backup it:

```
    sudo cp cacert.pem cacert.pem.old

    ls /usr/share/curl 
    > cacert.pem    cacert.pem.old
```

I remove it, and build a new one , with my self-signed certificate concatenated:

```
    sudo rm cacert.pem
    sudo sh -c 'cat cacert.pem.old /etc/ssl/self-signed/server.crt >> cacert.pem'

    ls /usr/share/curl 
    > cacert.pem    cacert.pem.old
```

and I use curl ... raising the error
Is there any additional process ( Mac OSX 10.9 - Mountain Lion) regarding keychain ?? before using curl w SSL ????

Comment: Very minor note, OSX 10.9 is Mavericks, 10.8 is Mountain Lion :)

Answer (score 1):

I added my self-signed certificate (/etc/ssl/self-signed/server.crt) to Apple keychain certificate ( as root certificate) , gave the authorizations ... AND
I RESTARTED MY COMPUTER .... this is a keypoint ... 
I don't know why my computer need to be restarted, but wo that the certificate is not recognized...